# How to convert a string to hex and vice versa in c?

Tags: c

How can i convert a string to hex and vice versa in c. For eg:, A string like "thank you" to hex format: 7468616e6b20796f75 And from hex 7468616e6b20796f75 to string: "thank you". Is there any ways to do this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `sprintf()` / `sscanf()` inside a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sprintf` and `sscanf` are good enough for this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char text[] = "thank you";
  int len = strlen(text);

  char hex[100], string[50];

  // Convert text to hex.
  for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < len; ++i, j += 2)
    sprintf(hex + j, "%02x", text[i] & 0xff);

  printf("'%s' in hex is %s.\n", text, hex);

  // Convert the hex back to a string.
  len = strlen(hex);
  for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < len; ++i, j += 2) {
    int val[1];
    sscanf(hex + j, "%2x", val);
    string[i] = val[0];
    string[i + 1] = '\0';
  }

  printf("%s as a string is '%s'.\n", hex, string);

  return 0;
}
```

Now

```
$ ./a.out
'thank you' in hex is 7468616e6b20796f75.
7468616e6b20796f75 as a string is 'thank you'.
```

Comment: I am trying to create an aes decryption script by passing a hex string and decode it as a string. Is there any aes working decryption script that you know ?

Comment: This answer assumes an ASCII (or compatible) character set.  Admittedly, that is pretty common in practice, but it is not required by the C standard.

Comment: If `text[i] < 0`, `sprintf(hex + j, "%02x", text[i]);` is an issue.  Better to insure only non-negative values are passed.  Code lacks bounds checking - yet does illustrate the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a string to its hexadecimal code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main( )
{
    int i;
    char word[] = "KLNCE";
    char hex[20];
    for ( i = 0; i < strlen ( word ); i++ )
    {
        char temp[5];
        sprintf( temp, "%X", word[i] );
        strcat( hex, temp );
    }
    printf( "\nhexcode: %s\n", hex );
    return 0
}
```

OUTPUT

```
hexcode: 4B4C4E4345
```

Answer (score 0):

straight forward solution:

```
public static string ToHex(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
    return Convert.ToHexString(bytes);
}
```

to convert back to plain text:

```
public static string FromHex(string str)
  {
      byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length / 2];
      for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
          bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(str.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);

      return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
  }
```

caller:

```
string hex = ToHex("my name is moe");
```

> returns: 6D79206E616D65206973206D6F65

```
string val = FromHex(hex);
```