# Why does converting string to hex need to be done with 0xff in C?

Tags: c, string, printf

Following on this question [How to convert a string to hex and vice versa in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46210513/how-to-convert-a-string-to-hex-and-vice-versa-in-c)?

I run the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str[] = { 0x58, 0x01, 0x02, 0x20, 0x22, 0x00, 0xC5};
    char hex[32] = {0}, hex2[32] = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(str); i++) {
        sprintf(hex + i*2, "%02X", str[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(str); i++) {
        sprintf(hex2 + i*2, "%02X", str[i] & 0xff);
    }

    printf("hex = %s\nhex2 = %s\n", hex, hex2);
    return 0;
}
```

I get this result:

```
hex = 580102202200FFFFFFC5
hex2 = 580102202200C5
```

I wonder why there is more `FFFFFF` without 0xFF?

Comment: Change `char str[] = ...` to `unsigned char str[] = ...` and the extra F's will disappear. Now, to really learn, you work out what difference that makes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many small pieces to the puzzle that needs to be put together.

To begin with it's implementation-defined if `char` is signed or unsigned.

If it's signed, then because of the common [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) the value `0xc5` will actually be *negative* (it will be the decimal value `-59`).

And when a small integer type (like `char`) is used as an argument to a variable-argument function like `sprintf`, then it will be [*promoted*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) to `int`. If the type is signed and the value is negative, it will be *sign extended*. So assuming the common 32-bit `int`, the signed and negative value `0xc5` will be promoted and sign-extended to `0xffffffc5`.

To solve this problem, the simplest solution is to simply use an explicit unsigned type like `uint8_t` (which basically is an alias for `unsigned char`).

Besides that I also recommend you use the `hh` format type prefix to explicitly say that the argument is a byte.

Put together change to

```
uint8_t str[] = { 0x58, 0x01, 0x02, 0x20, 0x22, 0x00, 0xC5};
```

and

```
sprintf(hex + i*2, "%02hhX", str[i]);
```

---

As for the difference made by `str[i] & 0xff`, it's because then you mask out the top 24 bits of the `int` value. So `0xffffffc5 & 0xff` becomes `0x000000c5`.